# Print newly persited entity's id right after form submission using CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

#### Shortly said

On submission of a new item, Symfony handles POST datas but newly persisted items do not have their id populated in their corresponding hidden field value attribute, the value attribute is missing instead.

#### Surgery:

I've implemented some add/edit/remove feature to let users manage a pool of "City" entities, using a [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).
When a new city is added:

- I made sure every existing entry has an hidden field holding the entity's id (pk), along with editable regular properties in order to update correctly existing instances
- On form submission, datas are available [*ok*]
- Persist loop and following flush successfully update database  [*ok*]
- Form gets rendered again with the newly added city

All is working except the fact that any new submitted city has their **hidden field missing «value» attribute**. [image]

I read things like
*Accessing objects getters right after flush returns the corresponding up to date properties. Newly inserted records ids get populated …*

So I expected Doctrine to update newly persisted city objects upon flush, but it looks like nothing is happening. **Form seems not to be aware of new insertions.**  Is this because of Forms datas immutability after a request gets handled ?
*Note:* At least, when reloading the page (reach the same URL without posting datas twice), hidden fields finally have their attribute value with corresponding entity's id printed.

Could someone help me spot what needs to be done here so that hidden fields (of newly inserted items) get correctly rendered (with «value» attribute containing expected entity id) right after submission ?

**Controller …**

```
<?php
// ...
/**
 * @Route("/cities", name="admin_config_cities")
 */
public function configureCitiesAction(Request $request)
{
    # Retrieving existing cities
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $cities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->findAll();

    # Associate cities ids with corresponding objects
    $sorted = [];
    array_walk($cities, function ($value, $key) use (&$sorted) {
        $sorted[ $value->getId() ] = $value;
    });

    # Initialize form
    $citiesForm = $this->createForm(
        CollectionType::class,
        $cities,
        [
            'entry_type' => CityType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            # I thought "mapped" option would do the trick.
            # worse, seems to do nothing
            'mapped' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'entry_options'  => [
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference'=>true
            ]
        ]
    );
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $citiesForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($citiesForm->isValid()){
            # Persist any submitted datas
            foreach( $citiesForm->getData() as $city ){
                $id = $city->getId();
                if ($id && array_key_exists($id,$sorted)) {
                    unset($sorted[$id]);
                }
                $em->persist($city);
            }
            # Remove discared cities
            foreach( $sorted as $removed ){
                $em->remove($removed);
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    # TODO: find the way to make newly added cities to be rendered
    # along with their ID available inside an hidden field's attribute
    # right after submission (without the need of a refresh)
    return $this->render('AppBundle:admin:config/cities.html.twig', [
        'form' => $citiesForm->createView()
    ]);
}
```

CityType contains an hidden field

```
//…
$builder->add( 'id', HiddenType::class, [ 'required'=>false ])
//…
```

Associated Template

```
{# … #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div data-prototype="{{ form_widget(collection.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for item in collection %}
            {{ form_widget(item) }}
        {% endfor %}
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="{{ 'button-add-title'|trans }}">{{ 'button-add-caption'|trans }}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <p class="text-right">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Hopping this is clear enough, thank you.

### EDIT

`by_reference` is set to true inside collection's `entry_options`.
Tests I've done say: it only has impact there. True make it possible to update corresponding (existing) records in DB. On the other hand, false prevents  mapping to be done therefore resulting in duplicate entries in database.
Setting `by_reference` on the collection itself simply seems to do nothing at all.
That said, new records are actually persisted, but modification of this newly created element leads to random behaviour (deleted because of allow_delete, duplicate entry issued). Still developper tool DOM tree does not show hidden field's `value` attribute, neither do navigator source shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+u</kbd>. Value attribute *magically* appears once a fresh GET request is made. 
There are definitly things I do not understand here `:/`.

In the end, the only way I found to make sure form is rendered with hidden fields correctly populated is to command `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl($_route));` after `flush()`.

Comment: Check out the last paragraphy of the [`by_reference`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference) documentation – it’s specifically about CollectionType. It might be unrelated to your problem, but you are manually reimplementing the semantics of `'by_reference' => true` on the CollectionType in your controller.

Comment: @Lumen Thank you for your time, I've edited my thread.